# Locking SQL Server tables or rows between methods

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, csv

I have a Winforms in C# that imports a CSV file.

The first method imports it but then calls a second method that opens a data connections and gets the last `logNumber` then returns and assigns the `logNumber++` to each record then writes out new last `logNumber` to the table.

During this time I don't want another user to be able to access the `logNumber` table (I also have to do this with `batchNumber`). If I use pessimistic locking from what I have found it only will lock them while connection is open so if I go to the second method it will close. So how do I keep it locked?

I thought I would define the `sqlconnection` at the form `lvl` (`public partial class frmCheckEntry : Form`) I receive an error. I also need to keep a lock on records (rows) (Loaded to a `datatable` then into a datagrid view) when I open a child form and make changes. This is a multiuser system but I need to prevent other users from having or even seeing records being worked on by a user.

Comment: Maybe you can show some code?

Comment: The concept you are looking for is a transaction

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to keep the connection and the transaction open. You said you got an error when you did that. You need to interpret the error message and fix it. Then, it will work.

You could also try to mark "locked" rows with IsLocked = 1. Other users reading that row would then need to show a message like "This item is currently in use".

Comment: Found the answer I think, I still need to finish testing but first things first the error I got was a syntax error "A field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field, method or property".
Now the solution I declare the sqlConnection at the form lvl but assign a empty connection sting:
            public SqlConnection lockCon = new SqlConnection(); 

then in my method I use the connection string property to assign the string:
         lockCon.ConnectionString = conStrn2;

Comment: This sets the connection at the form level  I can then used open.lockCon at the method lvl and it should stay open until I close it or the form is closed. I can now use the open the connection in the first method where I need to lock in my sql statment the table/record and then when I am done with I close the connection and the locks will be turned off.